# How to run actions if 2 sprites collide in sprite kit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I want to make two sprites disappear when they hit each other in sprite kit. The example in apple's documentation doesn't really help me that much so if you could explain it it would be good. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so you need to do several things.

I'm going to assume that you have two sprites...

```
SKSpriteNode *sprite1;
SKSpriteNode *sprite2;
```

These are currently flying around your scene and may or may not come into contact with each other.

So, you need to set everything up to enable hit testing and call backs.

First, add physics bodies to the sprites...

```
sprite1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:10];
sprite2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(10, 10)];
// this is a couple of examples, you'll have to set yours up to match the sprite size, shapes
```

Next you need to add categories to the sprites. This gives the physics engine some information about what type of body it is...

```
sprite1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = 1 << 0;
sprite2.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = 1 << 1;
// again this is an example. You probably want to put these in an NS_OPTIONS typedef.
```

Then you need to tell the physics engine which contact you want to be told about. In the is case you want to be told when sprite1 (1 << 0) comes into contact with sprite2 (1 << 1).

So...

```
sprite1.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 1 << 1; // it will test for contact against sprite 2
sprite2.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 1 << 0; // test against sprite 1.
```

Now in you scene you need to adopt `<SKPhysicsContactDelegate>` and set the scene to be the physics delegate...

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
```

And then create the method...

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    // these two physics bodies have come into contact!

    SKSpriteNode *firstContactNode = contact.bodyA.node;
    SKSpriteNode *secondContactNode = contact.bodyB.node;

    // now remove them...

    [firstContactNode removeFromParent];
    [secondContactNode removeFromParent];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SKAction* _vanishAction =[SKAction fadeOutWithDuration: 1];

    [sprite runAction:_vanishAction completion:^(void){
            [sprite removeFromParent];     
    }];
```